# How to add a Facebook share box with counter in a page

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, css, bigcommerce

Here is the code

```
<div>
   <a name="fb_share" type="box_count" expr:share_url="data:post.url" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

I have a problem in this code when my site is http://example.com then code is working properly. But when my site is https://example.com then its not working.

Simple "Share" text is showing in all https pages. Can you have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script tag to :

```
<script src="//static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript">
```

Notice the missing protocol (http:). This will allow the script to load wether on `https` or `http` by automatically choosing the correct protocol (assuming facebook provide a secure version!)

Comment: Thanks for sharing its working perfectly in Mozilla but problem remain same in Chrome.